# Need to get images from Firebase by using Stream builder in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream-builder

I am trying to get images from firebase by using StreamBuilder widget. Tried all what I know but no result. As classes connected with each other tight everything gets tangled. here images are retrieved from manually created list as indicated above but I want to replace them with images from firebase. Please review code and help

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
    static const String id = 'Myapp_screen';
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

var cardAspectRatio = 12.0 / 16.0;
var widgetAspectRatio = cardAspectRatio * 1.2;

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var currentPage = images.length - 1.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: images.length - 1);
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        currentPage = controller.page;
      });
    });

    return Scaffold(
         body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
              Color(0xEFEFEF),
              Color(0xFFFF),
            ],
                begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                end: Alignment.topCenter,
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp)),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 12.0, right: 12.0, top: 30.0, bottom: 8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          CustomIcons.menu,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          size: 30.0,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          size: 30.0,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Trending",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontSize: 46.0,
                            fontFamily: "Calibre-Semibold",
                            letterSpacing: 1.0,
                          )),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          CustomIcons.option,
                          size: 12.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFff6e6e),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 22.0, vertical: 6.0),
                            child: Text("Animated",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15.0,
                      ),
                      Text("25+ Stories",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CardScrollWidget(currentPage),
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: PageView.builder(
                        itemCount: images.length,
                        controller: controller,
                        reverse: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container();
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBottomBar(),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

And this is for card scroll

```
class CardScrollWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  var currentPage;
  var padding = 20.0;
  var verticalInset = 20.0;

  CardScrollWidget(this.currentPage);  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: widgetAspectRatio,
      child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, contraints) {
        var width = contraints.maxWidth;
        var height = contraints.maxHeight;

        var safeWidth = width - 2 * padding;
        var safeHeight = height - 2 * padding;

        var heightOfPrimaryCard = safeHeight;
        var widthOfPrimaryCard = heightOfPrimaryCard * cardAspectRatio;

        var primaryCardLeft = safeWidth - widthOfPrimaryCard;
        var horizontalInset = primaryCardLeft / 2;

        List<Widget> cardList = new List();

        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          var delta = i - currentPage;


          bool isOnRight = delta > 0;

          var start = padding +
              max(
                  primaryCardLeft -
                      horizontalInset * -delta * (isOnRight ? 15 : 1),
                  0.0);

          var cardItem = Positioned.directional(
            top: padding + verticalInset * max(-delta, 0.0),
            bottom: padding + verticalInset * max(-delta, 0.0),
            start: start,
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      offset: Offset(3.0, 6.0),
                      blurRadius: 10.0)
                ]),
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: cardAspectRatio,
                  child: Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(images[i], fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
                              child: Text(title[i],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 25.0,
                                      fontFamily: "SF-Pro-Text-Regular")),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 12.0, bottom: 12.0),
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 22.0, vertical: 6.0),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                child: Text("Read Later",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
          cardList.add(cardItem);
        }
        return Stack(
          children: cardList,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Manually created list of images

```
List<String> images = [
 "assets/image_04.jpg",
 "assets/image_03.jpg",
 "assets/image_02.jpg",
 "assets/image_01.png",
];
```

Comment: I don't see where you have tried to implement ```StreamBuilder```

Comment: I am trying to add StreamBuilder widget but don't know how to do it properly without errors.

Comment: you should post what you have tried that is giving you an error so we at least know where you want to implement it

Answer (score 1):

```
Please add below StreamBuilder Widget code...<br>

                  StreamBuilder(
                    stream: Firestore.instance
                        .collection('details')
                        .document(documentId)
                        .collection(collectionId)
                        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                        .limit(20)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                valueColor:
                                    AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green)));
                      } else {
                        listMessage = snapshot.data.documents;
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 5.0, right: 5.0, left: 5.0),
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                            reverse: true,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                buildItem(index, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ));
```

---

then make one method that return widget which contains layout of your ListView items.

---

```
Widget buildItem(int index, DocumentSnapshot document) {
             return Container(
                          child: CachedNetworkImage(
                            placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                valueColor:
                                    AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black),
                              ),
                              width: 200.0,
                              height: 200.0,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(70.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.lightGreen[200],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(8.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            imageUrl: document['imgUrl'],
                            width: 200.0,
                            height: 200.0,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help I really appreciate. But be honest I got confused. Should I add AspectRatio widget with its content inside StreamBuilder?

Comment: Unfortunately I have created standard ListView.builder and added all information from firebase into Card widget with list design. I had to delete all previous code as it was getting tangled whenever I tried to touch it.